# Why is part of my html code disappearing when I resize the page (bootstrap)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking at the bootstrap layout http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Boxify/ and there's a section with the iphone on the left side. When I resize the page and make it smaller - this device disappears. Is there  way of avoiding that and just putting the device below the text?

When I check out the source of this page I can see in html that this section is basically divided into two columns:

```
<section class="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-wrap">
            <div class="texture-overlay"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="device wp3">
                            <div class="device-content">

                            (...)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h1>Showcase your Product or Service</h1>
                        <p>(...)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and the CSS code for this section is as follows:

```
.showcase {
    background: url('../img/showcase-bg-fixed-01.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.showcase h1 {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.showcase p {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #fff;
}
.device {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: 20%;
    min-height: 676px;
    width: 359px;
    background: url('../img/iphone-skeleton.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.device-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    left: 56px;
    width: 247px;
    height: 445px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.device-content img {
    width: 247px;
    height: 445px;
}
.showcase-wrap {
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px 0;
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

I don't think it's the bootstrap thing, I rather think that the cause for that is somewhere in the custom CSS code itself...
What should I change in this code to always show the device?

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning *and* Bootstrap? I suspect that's probably the issue.

Comment: I think this is how the layout is built... is there a way of changing it so the final effect on the webpage is the same?

Comment: Bootsrap doesn't use absolute positioning...I'd suggest removing all that and seeing what happens. Failing that build a demo and we can take a look.

Comment: @RohitKumar the webpage online is here: http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Boxify/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the content's CSS is modified in a media query. Media queries are expressions that resolve to true or false. If the expression resolves to true the styles are applied.

In this case we have a media query that is modifying the CSS in some way for the class .device (the iPhone image).If you look at the file queries.css you will see the following media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
   .feature-1,.feature-2{margin-bottom:50px;}
   .device{display:none;}
   .screenshots ul li{width:50%;}
   .screenshots-intro{padding:110px 0 100px 0;}
   .feature-content{width:80%;}
   .features-slider{height:100%}
}
```

Since the screen size is > max-width: 991px, the expression resolves to true. In this case, notice that .device{display:none}. As a result, the iPhone image is no longer rendered.

To learn more about CSS Media Queries be sure to check out the follow links
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: thanks for your hint! Can I just remove this line: 
 .device{display:none;} and increase the height of showcase when looking at the smaller screens?

Comment: Sure. Of course you may need to make additional tweaks to get the page to look exactly like you want. Also, if you found this helpful, please be sure to mark it as the answer. Thanks!